# Ubuntu 14.04 can't recognize USB device

Tags: ubuntu, usb, usb-flash-drive, gparted

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and when I plug my USB key into my laptop it doesn't appear. I also tried to use Gparted to detect it but it doesn't exist here. But using Disks in my OS I can see it. So what's wrong? is it corrupted?

[image: Gparted && Terminal]

[image: Disks]

Comment: You Gparted display only shows the content of `sda`. To see the contents of `sdb` you have to select it (device selector in top right corner)

Answer (score 0):

As we can see it in your disks screenshot, try

```
mount /dev/sdb /mnt
```

then it shall return something like

```
mount: /dev/sdb is not a valid block device
```

This means your Ubuntu can detect the device.

In terminal, type:

```
sudo su
```

for root rights and then try

```
mkfs.xfs /dev/sdb1 && mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt -t auto
```

I am not near my linux PC, but this might work, try it.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the disk IS corrupted, the question will be is it hardware  or not. IF the device is being detected as /dev/sdb but nothing further it generally implies no partition table, but that generally shows as free space not lack of media.

So a few first things?
This is not a flash card reader is it. If so devices will show like this if the device is working but the card is unreadable.

Second:
There is no data you need/want to recover on it?

If this is the case, you can try erasing any memory it had of itself even being in any other state by using the flowing to overwrite the partitiion table.

> dd if=/dev/random of=/dev/sdb bs=1M count=5

If this succeeds the disk is functioning, pull it out reinsert it to see if that corrected it. It would then show free space and you could create new partition and use. (Although personally I would not trust it for anything important past this)

If this fails or generates error, then the disk its likely toast.